# Unable to call method in validation provider in cakephp 4

Tags: php, validation, cakephp-4.x

I'm creating a plugin FileManager and I'm trying to create a validation provider `FileValidation` in this plugin to provide some pre-build rules.

I've put `FileValidation` class in **plugins/FileManager/src/Validation/FileValidation.php** :

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace FileManager\Validation;

use Cake\Validation\Validation;

class FileValidation
{
    /**
     * Check mime type
     */
    public static function mimeImage($file): bool
    {
        return Validation::mimeType($file, [
                            'image/png',
                            'image/gif',
                            'image/pjpeg',
                            'image/jpeg'
                        ]);
    }
}
?>
```

When I try to use this mimeType method in a Table like this :

```
// in src/Model/Table/BlocksTable.php
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator = parent::validationDefault($validator);
        
        $validator
            ->allowEmptyFile('image')
            // [...]
            ->setProvider('file', \FileManager\Validation\FileValidation::class)
            ->add('image', 'fileHasMimeImage', [
                'rule' => 'mimeImage',
                'provider' => 'file',
                'message' => 'Bad mime type.'
            ]);
```

an InvalidArgumentException is thrown **Unable to call method "mimeImage" in "file" provider for field "image"**

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Try debugging `class_exists(\FileManager\Validation\FileValidation::class)` and `is_callable([\FileManager\Validation\FileValidation::class, 'mimeImage'])`. If the former is `false`, then you probably have an autoloader problem, if the former is `true`, but the latter is `false`, then you broke reality.

Comment: @ndm It seems that I have an autoloader problem.. How could I fix it ?

Comment: Depends on what's wrong with it. Refer to **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/plugins.html#manually-autoloading-plugin-classes**.

Comment: @ndm In my composer.json I have `"autoload": {"psr-4":{"App\\": "src/", "FileManager\\": "plugins/FileManager/src/"}}` and I've done `composer dumpautoload`, is something missing ?

Comment: That looks seemingly correct. If the class still comes up as nonexistent in the validation method, then you'll have to do more debugging, check the files exist, that they are accessible (for example file permissions), whether the naming is correct everywhere (case sensitivity can be an issue), whether the class file is even loaded, etc.